# Customizing identify form in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, features, html, identify

Is it possible to customize the identify form in QGIS (I am using version 3) to create Balloon like windows and add a picture in addition to the features extracted from the table?

Comment: It would be difficult to modify the existing dialog and it would cut your branch off if you modified the source making updates from the trunk painful at best but you can create your own in python, parsing your feature and picture. What programming/scripting languages do you know?

Comment: I just want to get the features automatically. In this case perhaps using Qt Designer would be a better option (?)

Comment: When I did a similar addon, but with edit capability, I used Qt Designer and python, that was a long time ago though so perhaps Qt has become easier to work with.

Comment: Do you need to use the identify form or could you use the ''map tip''  ?

Comment: Preferably  identify form.